# How to change text in a p tag in a navigation to title when user is in a specific section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I need JavaScript code to help me change text in navigation to the title of each of my sections when the user enters the section. (it will be a mobile app)

The following is a skeleton of my code. I have a header and footer so it always shows on the user's screen. The header tag is where I want my text to display screen title of each page. "home" will change to "specials" in section 2, "reservations" in section 3.

```
<header>
 <div id="topnav">
   <p> home</p>
 </div>
</header>
```

I have three sections, with class `home`, `specials`, `reservation`.

```
<section class="home">
   <div></div> //I have code here
</section>
```

Comment: add you full html.

Comment: Are your links working with ajax?

Comment: A navigation made up of paragraphs ... now that’s ghastly from a semantic point of view. *shudder*

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard actually. First of all, you need to use the `$(window).scroll(function () {});` from JQuery to find out where your current scroll position is.

Then you will have to compare all the sections offsets with your current scroll offset. The closest will be stored in a variable called result. Then just set the text of your `<p>` with the result value.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        //Current Scroll offset, You might need to change the number 0 to something else because of paddings & stuff.
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + 0;
        //Closest offset
        var closest = 0;
        //Result will be the Class of the closest section. This class will be used to set the subnav a text.
        var result;
        $("section").each(function () {
            var offset = $(this).offset().top;
            if (scroll - offset > 0) {
                closest = offset;
                result = $(this).attr("class");
            }
        });
        //Now set the value "result" as text of your <a> tag.
        $("#topnav p").text(result);
    });
```

Please note this code has not been fully tested but it should work in theory. I hope you can work with this.